# How to assign multiple lines of code to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to assign a code of block to a variable in Python. I just wanna know why what I did isn't working. Alternatively, I'd be happy to have a part of my code that only executes when I want. Thanks.

I have posted the code I tried below. I want Python not to execute it, unless told to.

```
day 3 = (print("welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("what is your height in cm? "))
bill = 0

if height >= 120:
    age = int(input("what is your age? "))  
    print("you can ride the rollercoaster " , end="") #end="" keeps the print output pointer in the same line
    if (age>=45) and (age<=55):
        bill = 0
    elif (age < 12):
        bill = 5
        print("and your ticket price is $5")
    elif (age <= 18):
        bill = 7
        print("and your ticket price is $7")
    else:
        bill = 12
        print("and your ticket price is $12")
    photo = input("do you want a photo taken? y or n. ")
    if(photo == "y"):
        print("we charge $1 per 5 photos.")
        photoamount = float(input("how many photos do you want to take?"))
        bill = (photoamount*0.2)+bill

    bill = format(bill, ".2f") #format turns intengers and floats into strings with decimal places. 
    print(f"your total bill is ${bill}")

else:
    print("sorry, you have to grow taller before you can ride :("))
```

Comment: Please clarify what the actual problem is

Comment: What is the intent of the first line `day 3 = (print("welcome to the rollercoaster!")`? `print` returns None, and the line has two syntax errors.

Comment: Can not understand what is you really want.

Comment: I want my code to run this part of the code when if the user inputs a string. EG:
if(string = "X"):
    Runs the whole code

Because right now the code is running automatically before the user inputs anything.

Comment: It seems to me you are asking for how to define a *function*. Research this term in the Python tutorial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_first_function():
    print("welcome to the rollercoaster!")
    height = int(input("what is your height in cm? "))
    bill = 0

    if height >= 120:
        age = int(input("what is your age? "))  
        print("you can ride the rollercoaster " , end="") #end="" keeps the print output pointer in the same line
        if (age>=45) and (age<=55):
            bill = 0
        elif (age < 12):
            bill = 5
            print("and your ticket price is $5")
        elif (age <= 18):
            bill = 7
            print("and your ticket price is $7")
        else:
            bill = 12
            print("and your ticket price is $12")
        photo = input("do you want a photo taken? y or n. ")
        if(photo == "y"):
            print("we charge $1 per 5 photos.")
            photoamount = float(input("how many photos do you want to take?"))
            bill = (photoamount*0.2)+bill

        bill = format(bill, ".2f") #format turns intengers and floats into strings with decimal places. 
        print(f"your total bill is ${bill}")

    else:
        print("sorry, you have to grow taller before you can ride :(")


print('line 001')

# you can call function /block of code/ whenewer you want
my_first_function()

print('line 002')
```